# Remove input[range] inner line

Tags: html, css, input

I would like to remove the inner line of the range-input (HTML5 Video Control). Is there any way?

[Have a Look!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox1je.png)

Comment: What does your actual markup for this look like? Additionally what browser are you using (as not all browsers render `<video>` elements the same.

Answer (score 0):

If this is simply an HTML `<video>` element then you are going to be rather limited as to how you can handle styling it. The appearance of these elements will differ from browser to browser as seen below :

**Firefox**

[image]

**Google Chrome**

[image]

**Internet Explorer**

[image]

**Edge**

[image]

These styles are extremely difficult and sometimes impossible to override (especially in any kind of consistent fashion) as they rely on styles that are browser-specific as seen below:

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline, video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    -webkit-appearance: media-slider;
    display: flex;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width: 25px;
    color: inherit;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: initial;
}
```

or specifically for the range section :

```
input[type="range" i] {
    color: rgb(196, 196, 196);
}
```

You could *try* to use a style that would explicitly override it, but your success may vary :

```
input[type="range" i] {
    /* Attempt to hide this */
    color: transparent!important; 
}
```

If you are looking for something like that, you would probably be better off using a Javascript-based like [JPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) or [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/)